# How do I connect my socket client to the socket server that resides in Google Cloud?

Tags: python, sockets, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to connect my socket client and my socket server. The socket server already resides in Google Cloud and upon testing the connection, it gives me the following error:

> TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

I copied the External IP Address of the VM's instance from Google Cloud and pasted it on the client' side.

Here's an example portion of the client' side where I pasted the IP address of the VM's instance:

```
s = socket.socket()
host = '127.0.0.1' #Just an example IP Address
port = 7000

s.connect((host, port))
data = s.recv(1024).decode()
```

I tried changing the port number from 7000 to 3389 and it says that the port is already used.

How can I successfully connect my client and the server?

Comment: Do you have the 7000 port open? or does the Firewall allow access to it? Try allowing access to that port by adding a rule [here](https://console.cloud.google.com/networking/firewalls/list)

Comment: If port 3389 is already used, that means a Windows system. Port 3389 is RDP (Remote Desktop). You must allow ingress for port 7000 in both the Windows Firewall and the Google Cloud VPC Firewall. Edit your question with more details and code for both sides.

Comment: We tried allowing ingress for port 7000 in Google Cloud and still it couldn't connect to the server. The client will be transferred to an Android device, because the Android App needs to connect to the server.

Here's the screenshot regarding with the settings that we set for allowing ingress access to port 7000: https://ibb.co/3hw1GXL

@Dharmaraj